# If $K_1 ⊇ K_2 ⊇ K_3 ⊇ K_4 ⊇...$ is a nested sequence of nonempty compact sets in $\Bbb R$ then the intersection $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ is not empty.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

If $K_1 ⊇ K_2 ⊇ K_3 ⊇ K_4 ⊇ ···$ is a nested sequence of
nonempty compact sets (in $\Bbb R$) , then the intersection  $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ is not empty.

I was interested in the proof, below:

Proof. In order to take advantage of the compactness of each $K_n,$ we are going
to produce a sequence that is eventually in each of these sets. Thus, for each
$n ∈ \Bbb N,$ pick a point $x_n ∈ K_n.$ Because the compact sets are nested, it follows
that the sequence $(x_n)$ is contained in $K_1.$ By definition of a Compact Set, $(x_n)$ has a
convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k} )$ whose limit $x = \lim x_{n_k}$ is an element of $K_1.$

In fact, $x$ is an element of every $K_n$ for essentially the same reason.

Given,

a particular $n_0 ∈ \Bbb N,$ the terms in the sequence $(x_n)$ are contained in $K_{n_0}$ as long as $n ≥ n_0.$ Ignoring the finite number of terms for which $n_k < n_0,$ the same subsequence $(x_{n_k} )$ is then also contained in $K_{n_0}.$ The conclusion is that $x = \lim x_{n_k}$ is an element of $K_{n_0}.$ Because $n_0$ was arbitrary, $x ∈\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ and the proof is complete.

---

But the thing is, I don't find any meaning whatsoever in the part, where they make the claim,

> "In fact, $x$ is an element of every $K_n$ for essentially the same reason" .

The word "same reason" might imply the reason they used for suggesting $x\in K_1.$ But I feel, that the same reason might  be applicable here since :

As $K_1$ contained all other $K_i's$, and so, $(x_n)$ was contained completely in $K_1.$ But when we look at $K_{j+1},$ then $(x_n)-\{x_1,x_2,...,x_j\}\in K_{j+1},$ and so we see, that we have excluded a finite number of terms from the sequence, or better say, we might formally assert that $j$ tail of $(x_n)$ is contained in $K_j.$ We know that, any $m$ tail of a convergent sequence converges a the same point as the parent sequence. So,$j$ tail of $x_n$ converges to $x,$ and as because, $K_{j+1}$ is a closed set we can certainly claim, $x\in K_{j+1}.$ But, as $j$ was arbitrary,  so, $x\in K_i$, $\forall i\in \Bbb N.$

I hope this is what the reason, the author wanted to convey by that line. I as a matter of fact, suggest replacing  the part in the solution :

> Given,
>
> a particular $n_0 ∈ \Bbb N,$ the terms in the sequence $(x_n)$ are contained in $K_{n_0}$ as long as $n ≥ n_0.$ Ignoring the finite number of terms for which $n_k < n_0,$ the same subsequence $(x_{n_k} )$ is then also contained in $K_{n_0}.$ The conclusion is that $x = \lim x_{n_k}$ is an element of $K_{n_0}.$ Because $n_0$ was arbitrary, $x ∈\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ and the proof is complete.

by the more simplified argument (which I wrote previously):

> As $K_1$ contained all other $K_i's$, and so, $(x_n)$ was contained completely in $K_1.$ But when we look at $K_{j+1},$ then $(x_n)-\{x_1,x_2,...,x_j\}\in K_{j+1},$ and so we see, that we have excluded a finite number of terms from the sequence, or better say, we might formally assert that $j$ tail of $(x_n)$ is contained in $K_j.$ We know that, any $m$ tail of a convergent sequence converges a the same point as the parent sequence. So,$j$ tail of $x_n$ converges to $x,$ and as because, $K_{j+1}$ is a closed set we can certainly claim, $x\in K_{j+1}.$ But, as $j$ was arbitrary,  so, $x\in K_i$, $\forall i\in \Bbb N,$ *which completes the proof.*

My argument is valid all the same because, when we are considering a particular $K_j$ we are excluding a finite number of terms at each step, but that does not affect the convergence of the sequence in any way (by a standard result in real analysis).

Am I justified in my reasonings and my proposed modification?

Comment: In full generality, the claim you are trying to prove is false. Are you working with metric spaces by any chance?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah, I am sorry I should've mentioned it. No, I am working with Real numbers. Nevermind, I have fixed it.

Comment: The author detailed his/her "essentially the same reason" by the detailed reasoning "Given a particular $n_0$ [...] $x=\lim x_{n_k}$ is an element of $K_{n_0}$". You understood it correctly but imo his/her style is better (lighter and very clear) than your reformulation.

Comment: @AnneBauval I dont get the meaning of "imo". I feel that's some sort of an abbreviation. But the thing is, my understanding is correct , right?

Comment: Authors often strive to express arguments concisely. This often forces a reader to think in order to fill out the argument with enough further details to satisfy themselves. That's what you've done, and that's fine, but I would not agree with this as a proposed modification.

Comment: Right, "you understood it correctly". Sorry: imo means "in my opinion". Usually one writes "imho" for "in my humble opinion" but as you can see, I am far from humble ;-)

Comment: @AnneBauval Ha ha, thanks a lot for your opinions. Your clarification was indeed  helpful.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the nice clarification you gave!